# SQL query returning column 'id' not found, when using spring boot to query MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm having a problem with spring boot where I'm trying to retrieve the count of unique entries from a MySQL database, however when running the following code the error: "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found." is returned.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pub) FROM entries WHERE username = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Pubs findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

if anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Comment: The error message does not match your code. Are you sure this is the code containing the problem?

Comment: findByUsername returns Pubs while the query returns a number, can you check on that ?

Comment: Try replacing `?1` with `:username`, since you seem to be using named parameters (c.f  the `@Param` annotation).

Comment: @Arnaud still the same error

Comment: @Yagnagurur that fixed the error, thank you. But it's returning 0 for some reason, I don't know if you can see why?

Comment: The table doesn't contain username you are looking for? I can see only that probable reason !!

Answer (score 0):

findByUsername returns Pubs while the query returns a number, probably you will have to change either one of those.